# Error Tomcat7-Selenium-Eclipse in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, selenium

I try to use selenium in my web services, but i have this error:

```
    exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    com.crunchify.restjersey.FtoCService.convertFtoC(FtoCService.java:29)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    com.crunchify.restjersey.FtoCService.convertFtoC(FtoCService.java:29)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
```

and more...

I use Eclipse Juno, Ubuntu 13.10 and Tomcat7, and i create a web services whit Jersey.
If i try to remove selenium code, it works, but with the selenium code not..

My class is:

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

@Path("/ftocservice")
public class FtoCService {

      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
      private StringBuilder verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();


      @GET
      @Produces("application/json")
      public Response convertFtoC() throws JSONException {

       driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
       baseUrl = "http://something.something.com/";
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
       driver.findElement(By.id("name")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='area']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/a/span")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("111111");
       driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("secret");
       driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.linkText("Something")).click();
       driver.quit();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        Double fahrenheit = 98.24;
        Double celsius;
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32)*5/9; 
        jsonObject.put("F Value", fahrenheit); 
        jsonObject.put("C Value", celsius);

        String result = "@Produces(\"application/json\") Output: \n\nF to C Converter Output: \n\n" ;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `xml-apis-2.10.0.jar` in your project library. please make sure you have that.

Answer (score -1):

It can't find:
    org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal

Where is your JAVA_HOME variable pointing??

Also, can you post your web-inf file?